# vSphere Cluster creation requirements

Tags: cluster-computing, virtual, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I've been searching around but haven't found a clear answer on this.

We're using VMware ESXI with vSphere to manage a handful of VMs (about 15 right now)
However, these are all spread over three separate machines.  I'm looking for a way to cluster these together so their resources can be pooled or dynamically allocated.  I found vSphere DRS Cluster information, but I'm having a really hard time finding out what I need to get that set up.

Does it require a separate vCenter license to hook into vSphere?  And at that point, how do I create a database to group all the server hosts together?  Every tutorial I find already has 2+ host machines already grouped together in the vSphere client, and I'm not sure how to go about achieving that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to create a failover cluster, then you need VMware HA. VMware DRS is the option for resource dynamical allocation. To manage these two options, you need a vCenter Server. vCenter Server Foundation can manage up to 3 hosts (which is your case). For more information about vCenter, see [this link](http://store.vmware.com/store/vmware/en_US/cat/ThemeID.2485600/categoryID.66249000?src=WWW_eBIZ_productpage_vCenter_Standard_Buy_US#pid-282870000).

For VMware HA and DRS to work, you must have a shared storage (NFS, iSCSI, or Fiber Channel). To know how to create VMware HA cluster using vSphere Client (connected to vCenter Server), see [this link](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.avail.doc/GUID-B53060B9-2704-4EE2-B97A-AE6FEBCE3356.html).

VMware DRS is an option after you created VMware HA. See this [link](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.resourcemanagement.doc_40/creating_a_drs_cluster/t_create_a_drs_cluster.html)